# jQuery nested Ajax calls not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, nested, jsonp, each

I'm trying to make nested ajax calls but the iteration does not work : let's say i have 2 companies with company number 1 having 2 contacts and company number 2 having 3 contacts. I Can't figure out why but the code given below displays the two company names followed by the five contact names : it is not nested....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#searchbutton').bind('click', function (event) {
            $("#result > h4, #result > p").remove();
            $("<p>Loading...</p>").appendTo($("#result"));
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: true,
                url: "http://localhost/archilab/archilabdirectory.svc/",
                data: ("tag=" + $("#searchstring").val()),
                success: function (companies) {
                    $("#result > p").remove();
                    $.each(companies, function () {
                        var outer = this;
                        $("<h4>", { text: outer.Name + " (" + outer.Perimeter + ")" }).hide().appendTo($("#result")).show(4000, function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                cache: true,
                                url: "http://localhost/archilab/archilabdirectory.svc/" + outer.Name + "/contacts/",
                                success: function (contacts) {
                                    $(contacts).each(function () {
                                        $("<p>", { text: this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName }).hide().appendTo($("#result")).show();
                                    });
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of issuing multiple ajax calls, why don't you club the names and contacts data into one single JSON response for a single ajax request?

Comment: And if, for some odd reason, you need two, please please please write functions.  Always code DRY (Don't Repeat  Yourself).  Whenever you can turn your code sideways and see mountains, you need to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that your `$.ajax` calls are asynchronous, right? This `each`:

```
$.each(companies, function () { /* ... */ });
```

Will add an `<h4>`, launch an asynchronous `$.ajax` call, and then repeat for the next entry in `companies`. The AJAX calls will almost certainly take longer to finish than the `$.each` so it will produce the company name `<h4>`s and then the AJAX calls will finish up and add the `<p>`s. There is no guarantee that the `<p>`s will even be added in the right order.

If you need things to happen in a specific order then you're going to have to add [`async: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your `$.ajax` calls.

**UPDATE**: I need a bit more space than a comment provides. No, this is not my last theorem.

You could push the `<h4>` stuff down into the inner success handler but this would still leave you open to ordering issues (i.e. the second AJAX call could complete before the first). I think the easiest thing to do would be to add wrapper `<div>`s with ID attributes around your `<h4>` and `<p>` elements, this would give you an easy target for a `.append` call; something sort of like this:

```
$.each(companies, function() {
    var $wrapper_hack = $('<div/>');
    $('#result').append($wrapper_hack);
    add_content($wrapper_hack, outer);
});

// And elsewhere...
function add_content($wrapper_hack, outer) {
    $("<h4>", {
        text: outer.Name + " (" + outer.Perimeter + ")"
    }).hide().appendTo($wrapper_hack).show(4000, function () {
        $.ajax({
            /* ... */
            success: function(contacts) {
                /* Build your <p> and append it to $wrapper_hack */
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The idea is to append content to something attached just to the right `<h4>` rather than appending to `#result`; then, everything will appear in the right order because you have embedded the correct order in your the HTML element nesting. You'll need `add_content` as a separate function to properly localize `$wrapper_hack` and `outer` to just the desired context and thus avoid the usual closure problems.

Comment: You're right i think it's actually what happens but as jQuery API says, "Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation"...so what would be the best solution to make it work without bringing back in one call all the companies and contacts together ?

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot ! As my prototype is 100% client oriented with "atomic" REST calls to retrieve data that really fit my needs. Thanks again.